# How do I reset a MultiIndex after slicing

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I'm often referring to the values in specific levels of a dataframe as a guide for what I'm supposed to do.  In this case, I'm slicing a dataframe using `pd.IndexSlice` and referring to the resulting dataframe's index.  The problem is that the resulting dataframe's index is the same as the original index.  I need it to be a subset of the original index where it respects the slices I've made.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

def produce_df(rows, columns, row_names=None, column_names=None):
    """rows is a list of lists that will be used to build a MultiIndex
    columns is a list of lists that will be used to build a MultiIndex"""
    row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(rows, names=row_names)
    col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(columns, names=column_names)
    return pd.DataFrame(index=row_index, columns=col_index)

df = produce_df([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']],
                row_names=['alpha1', 'alpha2'], column_names=['number1', 'number2'])

print df

number1          1         2     
number2          3    4    3    4
alpha1 alpha2                    
a      c       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       d       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
b      c       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       d       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The index looks like:

```
print df.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'alpha1', u'alpha2'])
```

Then I slice it:

```
islc = pd.IndexSlice[['a'], :]
df2 = df.loc[islc, :]
print df2

number1          1         2     
number2          3    4    3    4
alpha1 alpha2                    
a      c       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       d       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This is the expected slice.  What does the index look like:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=[u'alpha1', u'alpha2'])
```

`df.index.levels[0]` still has `'b'` in it.

## Question: How do I reset a `MultiIndex` after slicing.

Answer (score 0):

This works but is clumsy.  I feel like this should be an option somewhere I'm not looking.

```
df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2.index.to_series().values, names=df.index.names)

print df2

number1          1         2     
number2          3    4    3    4
alpha1 alpha2                    
a      c       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
       d       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

print df2.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a'], [u'c', u'd']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]],
           names=[u'alpha1', u'alpha2'])
```

The `'b'` is gone from `df2.index.levels[0]`